# Shapes (None, 16, 3) and (None,) are incompatible - Model not fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

So i have my X_train which is a numpy array of shape (13878, 16) containing vectorized comments, and their corresponding labels in Y_train with shape (13878,) containing an int from 0 to 2 stating if it is hate speech, inappropiate language or neither respectively.
however, when i try to fit my model, i get the error: Shapes (None, 16, 3) and (None,) are incompatible.

I already tried one-hot encoding the labels and therefore changing the loss function but it gave me a similar error and I unfortunately can´t think of what could be that I am doing wrong.

My vectorization and other relevant code is below:

```
max_features = 10000 #vocabulary size approx
sequence_length = 16 #comment length cap

vectorize_layer = layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length)

vectorize_layer.adapt(X.values) #adapt vectorizer for our vocabulary
vectorized_comments=vectorize_layer(X.values)
```

```
vectorized_comments_np = np.array(vectorized_comments) #from tensro to array to split

# First, split into training and the rest
X_train, X_temp, Y_train, Y_temp = train_test_split(vectorized_comments_np, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=Y)

# Now, split the rest into validation and test
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_temp, Y_temp, test_size=0.33, random_state=42, stratify=Y_temp)
```

#create model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  #layers.Flatten(input_shape=(16,)),
  layers.Embedding(max_features, 32),
  layers.Dense(128,activation="relu"),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(256,activation="relu"),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(128,activation="relu"),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")])

model.summary()
```

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[tf.metrics.Precision(),tf.metrics.F1Score(average="weighted")])
```

#fit

```
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=5,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val,Y_val),batch_size=64)
```

Error i get:   ValueError: Shapes (None, 16, 3) and (None,) are incompatible

I also tried expanding the dimension of Y but it didnt help, the error i got was  ValueError: Shapes (None, 16, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible

Answer (score 1):

### Cause of the `ValueError`

The `Embedding` layer returns a tensor of shape `(batch_size, input_length, output_dim)` as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding).

In your case, the output of the `Embedding` layer goes to the `Dense` layers (and `Dropout` layers also) which would simply take in inputs of shape `( batch_size , input_length , embedding_dim )` and return a tensor of shape `( batch_size , input_length , dense_dims )`.

In the last `Dense` layer, the `units` parameter is set to `3` and hence the output of the NN is `( batch_size , input_length , 3 )`
, whereas the size of the labels is `( batch_size , 3 )` which **do not match, hence resulting in a shape mismatch**.

### Solution

The outputs of the `Embedding` layer must be converted to a 2D tensor. This can be accomplished by:

1. Passing the outputs of an `Embedding` layer to any recurrent layers (`LSTM`, `GRU` or `RNN`). See the [docs on `LSTM`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM), specifically check the `return_sequences` argument as well.
2. Use global pooling layers, `GlobalMaxPooling1D` or `GlobalAveragePooling1D`.